Is there a way to target mobs using commands that have a specific amount of health?
I'm currently in Minecraft Java Ver. 1.20.4
I have a command aimed at a specific villager type already, I'd like to take said command and have it also be aimed at the villager only when it has about 1hp left or so.
For anyone curious, the command I have (and it works currently) is
/effect give @e[type=minecraft:villager, name=Fisherman] minecraft:poison infinite

I'd like to take that and add a different effect to the same villager only when it's low on health.
I looked into possibly delaying the effect, using a few tutorials from youtube but it didn't quite meet what I was looking for.
I did try looking for NBT data or anything adjacent but searches came up dry.
Preferably, I'd like to not have to add any mods for this.
I don't know if I got enough information in or not, I'm sorry if I missed anything vital, and thank you anyone who can help me.
Edit : Another option would be to only execute these commands on villagers with a specific trade. Like a fisherman who trades off buckets of fish.

You can by looking at the Health of any entity.
Take for example:
/say @e[nbt={Health:20f}]

(will list all entities with 20 HP, such as a newly spawned Zombie or Villager)
However, you can't "range" it like the other selectors, can only select based on the exact health of the mob. Because can have stuff like this:

or this:

This is because when you execute the nbt selector, it converts both the mob's data and your selector into a string, normalizes it and then performs a string comparison.

However, if you store the data into a scoreboard score...
/scoreboard objectives add health dummy {"text":"Health"}
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay health sidebar

... and run this every frame:
/execute as @e store result score @s health run data get entity @s Health


Now you can use target selectors and ranges!
Hurt your newly spawned entities a bit and then:
/say @e[scores={health=5..15}]

So, putting that back into your command:
 /effect give @e[scores={health=..2}, type=minecraft:villager, name=Fisherman] minecraft:poison infinite


Thank you aytimothy, I have a follow-up question though- a couple actually
Basically, how much in terms of the scoreboard is required for this to all work? I assume the display and say commands wouldn't be, correct?
And how would you recommend setting it up? (I can look up a tutorial for this question if needed)

The scoreboard setup is one one-off command (the second one is just for display) to create the scoreboard to track the values and the second (third, if counting the display command) is a repeating command that needs to be run ever tick to update the values (ideally you put it in a repeating command block set to always active).
Everything you need to blindly copy-paste is already in the answer :)

Best is to read the syntax and usage guides on the wiki

Okay, I think I get it. I'll be checking the wiki as well before I get started on my project again. Thank you tons, I'll keep tabs on if it works out or not. Thank you again aytimothy (:
